# How to replace a filed value for all the collection with the updated value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a book database, where every book is associated with a category when the category is updated corresponding entries in the book collection should be changed.

How to do this in mongodb?

Eg book1 belongs to category1 and when the category1 is edited to say categorynew know the book1 should be updated with new categorynew value rather than category1. I have to change to all the books which were in category1 to categorynew

Please assist how do this i am a newbie to nosql database?

Answer (score 0):

You can run an [`update`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) command on collection, filtering the books with old category and [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/set/) the new category.

```
db.books.update({category: "category1"},{"$set":{category: "category2"}},{multi:true})
```

And you have to do it whenever category name is updated.

The other way is to just keep the id of the category document, in book document, but that would require manual joining for displaying data.